# Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality will not work properly. (Android studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have gone through similar question on the internet. But I am still unable to find a solution for it.
To begin with I am trying to understand gradle and how android studio builds gradle files.
[I have read about gradle and how it is structured.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-gradle--cms-22978) I have understood that it is similar to make in linux, so it builds all of the necessary files to create apk. But i could not understand how android studio generates all the gradle files. Is there a main file which is executed and which generates all of the other gradle files.

My project was working properly until i had to sync the gradle files and now it is giving me "Gradle project sync failed" error. I have tried out existing solutions on the internet, like

1.Invalidating caches and Restarting
2.Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle turning on Online mode here, which i could not find on the android studio version 4.0.1
3.Opening up Gradle build console from View -> Tool Windows -> Gradle which i could not find.

[image: These are the only gradle files i can see currently in my project]

I can't see the module level and project level gradle files amongst others, should I manually add them?

[image: What does these .gradle folder structure mean? I tried pointing gradle file path to 6.1.1 but it did not work.]

Should i download a new gradle file and point it separately? Is there any way to fix it by executing the right gradle file and generating the rest of it.

Where can I read more about it and have a better understanding of gradle.

Comment: go to .gradle folder and delete files, then update android studio to version 4.1.1 and update all of sdk tools sub packeges in sdk manager.most android studio strange errors is because outdated packeges. if you live where google banned services for your country you need appropriate vpn for sync gradle

Answer (score 1):

Better install a new version of android studio. i think you have updated your gradle plugin.

Answer (score -1):

I had that problem and I just updated my Android studio. It worked!
go to: Help->Check for updates